# JSON.parse doesn't seem to parse object data?

Tags: javascript

I am communicating between iframes, but json.parsing to a var then using document.write to dump it doesn't contain anything. But if I `alert(e.data)`, it does.

```
<script>
window.onmessage = function(e) {

var j = JSON.parse(e.data);
document.write(j);
}
</script>

<script>window.postMessage("[1, 5, 'false']", '*');</script>
```

Comment: The string value `"[1, 5, 'false']"` is not JSON.  The string `'[1, 5, "false"]'` *is*. See http://json.org/

Comment: ... and perhaps the intention was actually `"[1, 5, false]"`?

Comment: Damn, so dumb sometimes!, thanks

Comment: Well, I also missed pointing that a string like "foo" doesn't have a `data` member.

Comment: A string may not, but the expected dispatched event argument does have a `data` member (as well as `origin` and `source`).

Answer (score 2):

For a correctly parse of a string into a JSON object strings keys and values must be wrapped by quotes `"`

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.parse()` is defined in [ECMA-262, fifth edition](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/), almost any browser supports it.

How to use it?

```
var json = '{"prop":"first","prop2":1}';
var o = JSON.parse(json);
```

If you're using jquery, it has a parse json function `$.parseJSON`, but its slower than native `JSON.parse`, so it's better to use the jquery function if the JSON object is not available.

```
var json = '{"prop":"first","prop2":1}';
var o = JSON && JSON.parse(json) || $.parseJSON(json);
```